# How to correctly redirect Wordpress in subdirectory with https?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have an issue with Wordpress installed in subdirectory of root and https.
The most I could get is to have frontend fully working over https, but the /wp-admin cannot be accessed due to redirection loop.

my wp current setup:

*FTP root structure:*

```
/.htaccess
/main-domain.com (WP folder with same name as the domain name)
/subsite-1.main-domain.com (3rd level domains, no connection to WP)
/subsite-2.main-domain.com
/...
```

*root .htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main-domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main-domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main-domain.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ main-domain.com/index.php [L]

# subdomain redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite-1.main-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subsite-1.main-domain.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subsite-1.main-domain.com/$1 [L]
```

*wordpress .htaccess (/main-domain.cz/.htaccess)*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

*/main-domain.com/wp-config.php*

```
define('WP_SITEURL','https://main-domain.com');
define('WP_HOME','http://main-domain.com');
// with WP_HOME set to "https://..." the site falls to redirection loop
```

I guess I just can't get my htaccesses straight, but also I'm afraid I'm "fighting" with WP internal redirects.

**Two main things I want to achieve is the site to always be redirected to https and the folder name (/main-domain.com/) not to be seen in URL**

Comment: Have you thought about not using the `.htaccess` to redirect, but to search and replace your database like this? Search for `http://subsite-1.com` and replace with `https://subsite-2.com`. That's how I always do it myself. Way cleaner and no messing around with `.htaccess` 's strange syntax.

Comment: And if `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` are both defined correctly in your `wp_options` table (as `siteurl` and `home`), they don't need to be defined in your `wp-config.php`. Also they should both be with `https`.

Comment: I've never come across this method in articles, stackoverflow etc. I feel like few rows in htaccess could solve my problem, instead of changing everything in database, but I can't figure it out, I was never good  with regular expressions. **I forgot to mention in original post I don't want the name of the folder to be seen in url.** Also I know about `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME`, but for debugging purposes it is easier for me to edit them through `wp-config.php`.

Comment: I can assure you that it is a better way to replace your database. Less redirects is always faster. Are the subsites physically in the directory of the main site? if that is the case, that would probably cause your redirection loop.

Comment: No, subsite folders are just 3rd level domains, that have nothing to do with the wordpress, I mentioned them just for illustration. Since there is no other replies, I'll try to rewrite all urls in the database. I'll let you know know if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `.htaccess` lines then.